# problem install pika (rabbitmq sdk in python ) in docker _ no module named 'pika'

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to install [rabbitmq](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (pika) driver in my python container, but in local deployment, there is no problem.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc python3.7 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python","index.py"]
```

this is my requerments.txt file :

```
requests
telethon
Flask
flask-mongoengine
Flask_JWT_Extended
Flask_Bcrypt
flask-restful
flask-cors
jsonschema
werkzeug
pandas
xlrd
Kanpai
pika
Flask-APScheduler
```

docker build steps complete with no error and install all the dependencies with no error but when I try to run my container it crashes with this error :

> no module named 'pika'

Answer (score 0):

installing python3.7 will not work here, you are still using `python3.8` by using `pip3` command and your `CMD` will also start `python3.8`, I suggest you to use `python:3.7` base image

so try this:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python","index.py"]
```

Comment: tnx for reply . but my problem still is there after the changes. moduleNotFoundError: no module named pika

Comment: can you try from inside the container ? `python` then `import  pika`

Comment: docker run -ti IMAGE_NAME bash